# I cannot find localsettings.php in my media wiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

The site is environment.wiki and hosted by greengeeks - I welcome all help on this project as I am not a developer :)

I need to find the localsettings.php file so I can
a. change the logo
b. get external links to open in a new tab
c. Figure out how to add a large library to the directory called phpspreadsheet
d. Update the media wiki version ( so far not able and unsure why)

All advice about running a media wiki site is welcome!  I picked media wiki because it seemed easy for others to help.

I looked everywhere in the file list for commonsettings or anything similar. Softalicious managed the install

Comment: It's `LocalSettings.php`. Under Linux, lettercase is relevant.

Comment: You mean [this wiki](https://environment.wiki/index.php/Main_Page) right?
You need server access to locate `LocalSettings.php`, probably via ssh or something. If you do not know what ssh is or how to access the server, you should ask the person who installed the wiki to do these things for you.

Comment: Yes that wiki and I am in the panel now.

Comment: Thank you - In local settings I still can;t tell what is the meta code line - and if I add the MediaWiki extension for SEO the site bricks.